# Can semanticscholar do exact title search?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics

I tried to search a paper using semanticscholar with exact titles. But it seems that it just treated the title as a list of keywords and gave only irrelevant results. Is that possible to have semanticscholar to treat the query as a phrase rather than keywords? I tried to put enclose the query with quotes but semanticscholar seems to ignore it.

Take the example search below,

https://api.semanticscholar.org/graph/v1/paper/search?query=%22semi-supervised%20classification%20with%20graph%20convolutional%20networks%22

It returns ten papers and none of them is the original one. And the paper above is not an obscure one but a popular paper with more than 10K citations.

Comment: Not an answer, but removing the "-" from the query in "semi-supervised" gives the paper you are looking for. Perhaps it sees the minus sign as asking to exclude the term right after it, as search engines commonly do?

Comment: Thanks! It is a nice catch. At least it returns the paper as one of the candidates.

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](https://www.semanticscholar.org/product/api) does not mention anything about specific title searches.

Depending on your needs, I would suggest the following approach:
`https://api.semanticscholar.org/graph/v1/paper/search?query=title:(%22semi-supervised%20classification%20with%20graph%20convolutional%20networks%22)&limit=1`

(Note that I added the `title`-tag, and a further `limit=1` to ensure that only the most relevant title is visible.)

Another possibility would be for you to download the bulk dataset and search for exact titles there.